# Head to end of list and back and move elem to index

Tags: haskell

I have list of strings

```
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

I wrote a first function, but it doesn't work

```
head_to_end :: [String] -> [String]
head_to_end x = t : h
    where h = `head` x
          t = `tail` x
```

I should get something like this

```
head_to_end ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"] -> ["2", "3", "4", "5", "1"]
last_to_head ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"] -> ["5", "1", "2", "3", "4"]

move_elem_1_to_4 :: Int -> Int -> [String] -> [String]
move_elem_1_to_4 ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"] -> ["b", "c", "d", "a", "e"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `(:)`, you need to move the head to the end using (++)

```
head_to_end x = tail x ++ [head x]
```

Remember, `(:)` is of type `a->[a]->[a]`....  You would need a single element on the left side, and a list on the right.  Your types were the reverse.

Also note that moving the head to the tail of a list like this is an expensive operation, the code will have to rebuild the full list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pattern matching to access the head and tail of the list separately, then append the head (as a singleton list) to the end of the tail of the list using the `++` operator.

```
headToEnd :: [a] -> [a]
headToEnd []     = []
headToEnd (x:xs) = xs ++ [x]
```

To move the last element of the list to the beginning, we can not use pattern matching, but we can use the `last` and `init` functions (imported with `Prelude` by default) in the `Data.List` module (from the base library) to access these values. This is where you would use the cons operator, `(:)`, to construct the new list with the values from `last` and `init`.

```
lastToHead :: [a] -> [a]
lastToHead [] = []
lastToHead xs = last xs : init xs
```

Look up the types of each operator `(:)` and `(++)` in GHCI. It makes it very clear why your examples do not work.

```
λ :t (++)
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
λ :t (:)
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

Here's the reference on [`Data.List`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-List.html) for info on the functions and operators I just mentioned. I found this page myself by visiting [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/), then searching for "Data.List", then clicked on "base Data.List" which was the first result.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @SmokeDispenser Thanks for pointing that out. Explanations added.